# How to iterate over rows and index in a DataFrame in Pandas to filter bolean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance, outliers

I am working in a project to find anomalies though some stock market tickers, fishing abnormal volumes... I'm struggling to filters the True values(those pass in the 'filter').
The main objective is create a data frame with the tickers that passed on the ' stats filter'.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas  as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
```

Get data frame

```
tickers = ['F', 'GE', 'GM','TSLA']
data = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
data[t] = web.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2020-1-1')['Volume']
```

Stats filters

```
data_std = data.std()
data_mean = data.mean()
anomaly_cut_off = data_std * 3
upper_limit = data_mean + anomaly_cut_off
```

Data frame with boolean values (True or False)

```
outlier = data > upper_limit
```

Anomalies should be a data frame with the DATE(index) and the ticker ('F', 'GE', 'GM','TSLA') just if is True... The code below worked if i change the pd to np.array(data), but just with one tickers.

```
anomalies = []

for outlier in data:
  if outlier > upper_limit:
  anomalies.append(outlier)
return anomalies
```

Comment: Do you want the rows which have at least one True, or something else?

Comment: Yes the rows with True, but I need the date which is the row index +  tickers which is the column. Something like Ticker X - date 2020-01-03

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the rows where at least one your tickers is `True`, this works:

```
outlier[outlier.any(axis=1)]
```